# Unexpected python loop output

Tags: python, loops

I'm working on a script to download the images from mangareader, and I've been trying to do it with Python since this is the first language I've learn throughly and I'm really into at the moment. The problem is that the output from the loop I've made is not working the way I was expecting to be.

```
soup = soup.findAll('option') # We select all the option tags
for l in soup: # And we start with a loop
    l = l.get_text()
    print l
    url = url + str(l)
    print url
```

The output I was expecting was:

```
1
http://www.mangareader.net/witch-shop/1/1
2
http://www.mangareader.net/witch-shop/1/2
3
http://www.mangareader.net/witch-shop/1/3
4
http://www.mangareader.net/witch-shop/1/4
5
http://www.mangareader.net/witch-shop/1/5
[...]
```

And what it shows is:

```
1
http://www.mangareader.net/witch-shop/1/1
2
http://www.mangareader.net/witch-shop/1/12
3
http://www.mangareader.net/witch-shop/1/123
4
http://www.mangareader.net/witch-shop/1/1234
5
http://www.mangareader.net/witch-shop/1/12345
[...]
```

And I can't figure out the why.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are appending `l` to `url` on every iteration without initializing `url`.

You should do:

```
#....
url2 = url + str(l)
print url2
#....
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, on each iteration you do

```
url = url + str(l)
```

which appends digits to `url`, and it's never reset.

To get desired output, try

```
for l in soup:
    l = l.get_text()
    print l
    print url + str(l)
```

This way you don't change the contents of the `url` variable.

Comment: Thank you as well for your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing the following

```
 url = url + str(l)
```

You are actually appending to the string, not adding 1 to it.

Comment: @LeandroPoblet Welcome to stackoverflow. Its great to know that we helped but you really don't need to thank everyone :P

Comment: @LevLevitsky All I'm saying is it might get a bit ... difficult at some points. :)